# Difference between medium fast and fast medium bowler?

Tags: cricket, terminology

What exactly is the difference between a medium fast bowler and a fast medium bowler?

At first they seem like they have no difference at all but then, you hear commentators and experts talk about a bowler and you suddenly feel like there is a difference. I know for sure that it is there.

So what is the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to http://www.talkcricket.co.uk/guides/types_of_fast_bowling.html

Medium-Fast bowlers tend to be in the 120-129 km/h range. While Fast- Medium bowlers are in the 130-141 km/h range.

Although the differences tend vary from source to source, notably the website Espncricinfo uses the term interchangeably (Source: Wikipedia)

Answer (score 2):

Fast-medium is a pace bowler who bowls slightly slower than a true 'express' fast bowler and relies more on seam and swing to get his wickets. Virtually all international pace bowlers (ie not spinners) are 'fast-medium' with only the odd true 'fast' bowler playing today.

Medium-fast is generally a part time bowler who is normally in the team mainly as a batsmen, but bowls quicker than the usual 'military medium' most part timers bowl. Specialist bowlers are never 'medium-fast' and it would be an insult to call one such.

Of other terms used, 'medium' is the pace a typical part time bowler bowls, while 'slow' is just another word for a Spinner. The terms 'slow-medium' and 'medium-slow' are archaic - if you spin the ball you are a slow bowler, if you dont you are at least a medium pacer, whatever speed you bowl at.

Comment: Try to add references to your answer, your answer seems opinion based. Usually the difference between them is their speed only it has nothing to do with if they are batsman are not. So, please improve your answer before you attract downvote.

Comment: This description makes a lot more sense than talking about just speed.